# Use std::cmp::Reverse with binary_search_by_key

Tags: rust

How to use `std::cmp::Reverse` with `binary_search_by_key`? Example: [Rust-Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8e5492b2cbd7d8d179ee73deaa12eff7)

The documentation to Rust's Vec::binary_search_by_key [says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.binary_search_by_key):

> Assumes that the slice is sorted by the key, for instance with sort_by_key **using the same key extraction function.**

In the minimal example below, I am using the same extraction function -- but no luck.

```rust
use std::cmp::Reverse;

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    v.sort_by_key(|&num| Reverse(num));
    println!("{:?}", v);
    let index = v.binary_search_by_key(&1, |&num| Reverse(num));
    println!("Res: {:?}", index);
}
```

This complains about *mismatched types*: "expected integer, found struct `std::cmp::Reverse`".

```sh
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:51
  |
8 |     let index = v.binary_search_by_key(&1, |&num| Reverse(num));
  |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected integer, found struct `std::cmp::Reverse`
  |
  = note: expected type `{integer}`
           found struct `std::cmp::Reverse<{integer}>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Careful inspection of the function signature gives the answer.

```
pub fn binary_search_by_key<'a, B, F>(
    &'a self,
    b: &B,
    f: F
) -> Result<usize, usize> where
    B: Ord,
    F: FnMut(&'a T) -> B,
```

`B` is the return value of the function, and also the first argument (after `&self`).

Therefore we have to add `Reverse` to the first argument as well:

```
v.binary_search_by_key(&Reverse(1), |&num| Reverse(num))
```

Comment: Genius! thanks! (And yeah, we're not supposed to make comments just with thanks... but I'm doing it anyway. Thanks for your help!)